# Jenkins: how configure role control for an user (remote) to only see specific Folder(s) and View(s)

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Working with `Jenkins` assume the following situation

From the server computer exists the following created by and available to the `admin`

```
Folder One
 View 1
   Job A
   Job B
   Job C
 View 2
   Job D
   Job E
   Job F
 View 3 (For other Users mostly remote)
   Job A
   Job F

Folder Two
 View 11
   Job AAA
   Job BBB
   Job CCC
 View 22
   Job DDD
   Job EEE
   Job FFF
 View 33 (For other Users mostly remote)
   Job AAA
   Job FFF

Folder Three
  View Alpha
    Job 111
    Job 222
  View Beta
    Job 333
    Job 444
  View Zulu
    Job 555
```

From above `Folder One` and `Folder Two` and `Folder Three` represent different projects, each `Folder` has its own `Jobs` grouped by `Views`. How you can see `View 3` and `View 33` (and not `View Zulu`) were created only to be allowed be accessed by other user, it mostly remote.

**Request** what I need is that `UserX` *once has logged, then automatically* can see just the following:

```
Folder One
 View 3 (For other Users mostly remote)
   Job A
   Job F

Folder Two
 View 33 (For other Users mostly remote)
   Job AAA
   Job FFF
```

Practically almost the same than the first *directory* `Folder` structure but how you can see:

- Only two Folders of three
- For each Folder (project), just one View

I watched these videos on youtube:

- [Jenkins Beginner Tutorial 5 - How to create Users + Manage + Assign Roles](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QvFungzXI5s)
- [Jenkins Tutorial For Beginners 10 - Using the Role-Based Authorization Strategy + Manage Roles](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v-AVR0UoB-c)

The videos are valuable, they work with the [Role-based Authorization Strategy](https://plugins.jenkins.io/role-strategy) plugin, but do not cover the scenario requested *and* they are only based to apply control to specific `Jobs`

Thus the `UserX` once has logged would see:

```
   Job A
   Job F
   Job AAA
   Job FFF
```

How you can see, the presentation or structure is not very adequate or friendly at a first glance how the requested structure.

Even when would be possible to work with regex or name patterns (such as: `Test*` or `Java*`) thanks to the plugin, it is not always possible to apply this rule (it in case if you are considering to think about `Remote*`).

The `Folder`, `View` and `Jobs` *components* are requested to have any name and not be very tight to some name pattern, to let change *any name* of *any component* when be necessary (practically any time).

**Note** consider the scenario where for `Folder Two` is added `View 44` with `Job ABC` and that `View` and `Job` must available for `UserX` (*and/or* for `UserY` - and it has other role different than `UserX`)

How accomplish this? Some other plugin to consider?

Comment: Have you looked at [Folder Authorization](https://plugins.jenkins.io/folder-auth)? Haven't tried myself, so can't comment. They share a [gitter channel](https://gitter.im/jenkinsci/role-strategy-plugin) w/RBAC team for feedback.

Comment: I am going to test it, but it has a few value about `Installs: 279`

Comment: Well, it was only released in beta in July and 1.0 in August, so it's barely 3.months old.. but if it works for you ...